NCS1S2403SC circuit help
I need some help to finish an experiment of sorts. I am working with a NCS1S2403SC voltage regulator and previously I was working with another voltage regulator. There is an image of that circuit down bellow.
The question is how to set up the circuit to work and if I require to use an alternating current on any of the pins of the NCS1S2403SC voltage regulator. The task also specifies that I replace the previous voltage regulator with the NCS1 one.
Note: Resistor used is 18 Ω.


Welcome! Text mentions resistor but your schematic does not include one.
